# super() in Python 2.x without args

Tags: python

Trying to convert <s>`super(B, self).method()`</s> into a simple nice `bubble()` call.
**Did it**, [see below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706623/super-in-python-2-x-without-args/2706703#2706703)!

Is it possible to get reference to class B in this example?

```
class A(object): pass

class B(A):
    def test(self):
        test2()

class C(B): pass

import inspect
def test2():
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    cls = frame.[?something here?]
    # cls here should == B (class)

c = C()
c.test()
```

Basically, `C` is child of `B`, `B` is child of `A`. Then we create `c` of type `C`. Then the call to `c.test()` actually calls `B.test()` (via inheritance), which calls to `test2()`.

`test2()` can get the parent frame `frame`; code reference to method via `frame.f_code`;
 `self` via `frame.f_locals['self']`; but `type(frame.f_locals['self'])` is `C` (of course), but not `B`, where method is defined.

Any way to get `B`?

Comment: If I may ask... what do you need this for? Cause I hardly think that something like this can be the best method for anything.

Comment: I'm actually trying to simplify doing `super(B, self).test()` for users with some kind of simple `bubble()` call. Actually, I've already found a way.

Comment: Couldn't you do `super(self.__class__, self).test()`?

Comment: @WoLpH: No, because first argument might be "this class" not `self.__class__` which might be a subclass of "this class".  If that worked, why wouldn't Python do that itself and eliminate first argument as excessive?

Comment: @Slava: AFAIK in Python 3 `super` can be called without arguments.  Though I guess you want that for Python 2.x.

Comment: @Doublep: I'm not claiming it always works, I'm just saying that you can use a method like that to get it working. This works only for single level inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a shorter way to do `super(B, self).test()` -> `bubble()` from below.

(Works with multiple inheritance, doesn't require arguments, correcly behaves with sub-classes)

The solution was to use `inspect.getmro(type(back_self))` (where `back_self` is a `self` from callee), then iterating it as `cls` with `method_name in cls.__dict__` and verifying that the code reference we have is the one in this class (realized in `find_class_by_code_object(self)` nested function).

`bubble()` can be easily extended with `*args, **kwargs`.

```
import inspect
def bubble(*args, **kwargs):
    def find_class_by_code_object(back_self, method_name, code):
        for cls in inspect.getmro(type(back_self)):
            if method_name in cls.__dict__:
                method_fun = getattr(cls, method_name)
                if method_fun.im_func.func_code is code:
                    return cls

    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    back_self = frame.f_locals['self']
    method_name = frame.f_code.co_name

    for _ in xrange(5):
        code = frame.f_code
        cls = find_class_by_code_object(back_self, method_name, code)
        if cls:
            super_ = super(cls, back_self)
            return getattr(super_, method_name)(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            frame = frame.f_back
        except:
            return



class A(object):
    def test(self):
        print "A.test()"

class B(A):
    def test(self):
        # instead of "super(B, self).test()" we can do
        bubble()

class C(B):
    pass

c = C()
c.test() # works!

b = B()
b.test() # works!
```

If anyone has a better idea, let's hear it.

*Known bug:* (thanks doublep) If `C.test = B.test` --> "infinite" recursion. Although that seems un-realistic for child class to actually have a method, that has been `=`'ed from parent's one.

<s>*Known bug2:* (thanks doublep) Decorated methods won't work (probably unfixable, since decorator returns a closure)...</s> Fixed decorator proble with `for _ in xrange(5)`:  ... `frame = frame.f_back` - will handle up to 5 decorators, increase if needed. **I love Python!**

Performance is 5 times worse than `super()` call, but we are talking about 200K calls vs a million calls per second, if this isn't in your tightest loops - no reason to worry.

Comment: I'm not sure it will work for decorated functions.  Also, I hope performance is not important at all in your usecase for `bubble()`.

Comment: Another (quite unlikely in real use) bug: if subclass `def foo...`, then does `bar = foo` then `bubble()` in `bar()` won't work as excepted because `method_name` will be incorrectly evaluated to "foo".

Comment: bar = foo: If I do `B.test_alias = B.test` and then `c.test_alias()`, it calls `A.test()` as expected.  Performance seems to be OK, 5000 ns (nanoseconds) for bubble() vs 900ns for super(...). This is a drop, but I don't see it as a huge one.

Comment: Ah, right.  For `super()` emulator that's exactly what's needed and is even the same what would happen if the method did direct call to parent's implementation.  I guess it's time to sleep, I'm making too many logical errors ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although this code should never be used for any normal purpose. For the sake of answering the question, here's something working ;)

```
import inspect

def test2():
    funcname = inspect.stack()[1][3]
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    self = frame.f_locals['self']

    return contains(self.__class__, funcname)

def contains(class_, funcname):
    if funcname in class_.__dict__:
        return class_

    for class_ in class_.__bases__:
        class_ = contains(class_, funcname)
        if class_:
            return class_
```

Comment: Well, that's basically what I did below, however don't you think that using inspect.getmro() is better than __bases__ ?  Also you don't test that the function is actually the one that called it, class `C` might have `test` function too. My answer takes care of that.

Comment: Indeed, I just couldn't find the mro method so I emulated it myself. Your method is definately better. Although I still argue that both are the wrong solution.