# How to avoid boilerplate when using super(...) in Python 2.6+?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, python-2.6, super

Are there good (suitable for using in real projects) ways or reducing boilerplate in things like this

```
class B(A):
    def qqq(self): # 1 unwanted token "self"
        super(B, self).qqq() # 7 unwanted tokens plus 2 duplications ("B", "qqq")
        do_something()
```

I want it to look more like this:

```
class B(A):
    def qqq:
        super
        do_something()
```

or (more realistically)

```
class B(A):
    @autosuper_before
    def qqq(self):
        do_something()
```

Is it possible in Python 2.6+ without overt hacks?

@link [super() in Python 2.x without args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706623/super-in-python-2-x-without-args)

Comment: No point in fighting the `self` parameter. Explicit is better than implicit, special cases aren't special enough to break the rules, yadda yadda yadda. Besides, how often do you override a method with no parameters and don't do anything before calling the next implementation?

Comment: What do you mean by "overt hacks"?

Comment: @BrenBarn, "Overt hacks" here means "Code becomes little bit simpler at the price of massive slowdown or ugly backtraces or something other unpleasant".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**

As the OP said "Is it possible in Python 2.6+ without overt hacks?", the answer is: **No**

**Long version**

<strike>You can make a simple decorator that will call the next parent with this method. The problem is that you will not have control on the arguments you want to pass.</strike>

**Edit:**
This will not work for a subclass already using `autosuper` because it'll chose the wrong class and make an infinite loop.

```
def autosuper(fn):
    def f(self, *args, **kw):
        cl = super(type(self), self)
        getattr(cl, fn.__name__)(*args, **kw)
        return fn(self, *args, **kw)
    return f
```

**How could this be done? Python 3.x do have a `super` function that takes no arguments!**

Unfortunally, the Python 3.x's `super` is a *class* and at the same time a *keyword*, because just the presence of its name will change the current environment to unveil a variable named `__class__` that is the right class you need to use!

If you check the frame inside a function declared in a class, there's no `__class__` variable and the `co_freevars` attribute of the frame's `f_code` attribute is empty. When you write the name `super` (do not need to call it), the `__class__` string will appear in `co_freevars` meaning it comes from another closure. Also, if you try to access the `__class__` variable without using super, it'll use the `LOAD_DEFER` bytecode for this same reason instead of `LOAD_GLOBAL` like would be normal to every undefined name.

This is so crazy that you cannot just do `hyper = super` and call this new `hyper` variable without arguments (that is exactly the same object as `super`).

As I cannot compete with this much of black magic inside the Python Interpreter, and because the `autosuper` decorator is not declared inside a class (so it can never access the `__class__` variable even if that was possible in Python 2.x), I will not try to write a new decorator and will leave this answer here as a warn for other people who want to do that.

It is probably possible to make some hackeries to find the right class to use, but I will not dig that far. Things to consider:

- When the decorator is applied, the class do not exist yet, so this should be done when the decorated function is called.
- The function being decorated is not yet an `unbound method` (that were removed anyway from Py3k) so you cannot check the `im_class` attribute.
- The frame does not seem to hold any information of the class used to make this call (unless of course the `__class__` variable do exist and it is possible to get a reference to it)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706703/754991) provided by OP is also quite broken because it makes a lot of bad assumptions and has problems with decorated functions.

Comment: (I'm just forgetting to add "self" again and again. (Also forgetting to change arguments or "super" in numerous methods when I change the name of the class or name of method).

Comment: Should it work reasonably fast? It looks a bit like Java's reflection which is said to be slow. Can the "reflection" be moved from "f" (to keep it lightweight) to "autosuper" and let "f" to call already prepared thing? (Actually I want something like Lisp macros that will just add that "super(...)" line automatically)

Comment: @Vi. Java reflection uses a similar syntax but is very different from decorators. It will just add one extra function call. BTW, I changed the code to use the `super` function instead of writing my own

Comment: This approach will not work if you add an additional level of inheritance (i.e., a `class E(D)` that also uses autosuper).  In this case `type(self)` will evaluate to E so `D.foo` will try to call itself and lead to infinite recursion.

Comment: The issue seems to be restricting enough to prevent the real usage this decorator. How to access the class's type where the decorator is being applied to use it instead of type(self)?

Comment: @Vi. I was checking how Python 3 can have a `super` without arguments and it uses a lot of black magic and a hidden variable named `__class__` only available when writing the function inside the class. So I could not reproduce this behavior on Python 2.x where this variable does not exist (and the decorator is declared outside the class). You can make a decorator and pass the right class name but that would be an "unwanted token"...